# SqlDependancy is firing more times

Tags: sql, asp.net, signalr, sqldependency

Hi i am trying to implement sqldependancy with signalr for new database changes. but the problem is if i edit only one row then also sqldependancy is firing more time. and some time it is not firing. I have web application without MVC. bellow is my code

```
 public void page_load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //notification.GetAllUnreadSalesNotifications();
            NewScrapNotifications();

        }



        public void NewScrapNotifications()
        {


            string message = string.Empty;

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(IFTDAL.IFTCommon.DSN))
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Message] FROM [dbo].[DummyData]";

                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {
                    command.Notification = null;
                    SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
                    dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
                    connection.Open();
                    SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

                    if (reader.HasRows)
                    {
                        reader.Read();
                        message = reader[0].ToString();
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
            {
                IFTHub nHub = new IFTHub();
                nHub.NotfiyAllClients();
               // NewScrapNotifications();
                //LoadDashboardByDashboardViewID(1);
            }
        }
```

and I also have bellow code in Globa.asax

```
 void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                // Code that runs on application startup
                RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
                BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
                SqlDependency.Start(DAL.DSN);

            }
            protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                SqlDependency.Stop(DAL.DSN);
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating new SQLDependency on each page load (refresh). I bet there is correlation between number of page reloads and number of notifications page is receiving via SignalR.

Register your notification only once per app lifetime...

Comment: "Register your notification only once per app lifetime" means where should i register ? should i register in Application_Start ?

Comment: Yes, it worked but i had to register my dependency in dependency_OnChange.

Comment: You mean you need to repeat registration in `SqlDependency.OnChange` handler every time it is invoked ?

Comment: Yes, else it will fire only once !

Comment: Well in that case my answer is not so correct ;) It really [seems](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh(v=vs.80).aspx) notification is only fired once. It explains why your code is not firing OnChange event sometimes but it does not explain multiple events on single row change...unless of course the events fired are of different type

Comment: Event fired are of same type ! I don't know but your solution worked like a charm ;)

Comment: answer is not so correct ? which answer is all correct ? `SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);` in Page_load ?